# How to delete published branch without creating pull request on github console

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request, branching-and-merging

Is there any way to delete the published branch without creating a pull request and merging it into the default branch on the GitHub console.

One way I know is to create a pull request and then close it, then I am able to delete that branch.

Edit :-
I could not find exisiting question on SO with below conditions -

1. How to delete branch without raising pull request.
2. How to do it on GitHub website.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+delete+branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found a solution for this.

Click on the branches tab shown below -

[image]

Delete your published banch from the list -

[image]